# observable of array of arrays of objects to observable of array of objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a zip operator that returns this `[ [Obj1, Obj2, ...], [Obj1, Obj2, ...] ]` and currently I do this to obtain what I want

```
map(x => [...x[0], ...x[1]])
```

is there an operator that does this ?

Comment: make you of the `map` operator to transform the observable stream

Answer (score 1):

Spreading the values of two arrays into a new array feels a bit redundant, why not `concat` the value together? `arr[0].concat(arr[1])`.

AFAIK there is no operator to do exactly what you want besides the `map` operator. The higher-order Observable functions will remove one layer of arrays so `mergeMap: [[],[]] => [],[]` but then you have two emissions instead of one big array.